# Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_save()... while uplaoding user picture programatically

Tags: users

I have two drupal 7.x sites, and I am uplaoding user picture programtically using the bleow code. In one site it is working fine and another one is getting fatal error as shown below. what could be the problem here..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_save() in /...
```

Code to upload user picture programatically.

```
$tmp_photo_realpath = "images/".$userimgname;
        $tmp_photo = "images/".$userimgname;
          $file = new stdClass();
          $file->uid      = $uid;
          $file->status   = 0; // mark the file as temporary
          $file->filename = basename($tmp_photo_realpath);
          $file->uri      = $tmp_photo;
         // $file->filemime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($tmp_photo_realpath));
          $file->filesize = filesize($tmp_photo_realpath);
         $infofile = explode("/",$tmp_photo);   
        $infoext = explode(".",end($infofile));
        $imgext = end($infoext);

      // The file should be an image
      $errors = array();
      $errors += file_validate_is_image($file);
      $errors += file_validate_image_resolution($file, variable_get('user_picture_dimensions', '100x100'));
      $errors += file_validate_size($file, variable_get('user_picture_file_size', '30') * 1024);

      // Make sure file extension is a valid image
      if (!in_array(strtolower($imgext), array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
        $errors[] = ' invalid image file extension.';
      }

      if (count($errors)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Profile Image Import:') . ' ' . $errors[0], 'warning');
        // Clean up (set fid to avoid error messages)
        $file->fid = 0; file_delete($file);
      }
      else {
        // We'll need a valid file id on the file object; file_save() will give us one
        $file = file_save($file);
        // Update user account (fid is not empty, status is temporary -- image
        // will be moved to proper directory and assigned to the user)
        $fields['picture'] = $file;
        $account = user_save($account, $fields);
    }
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? [`file_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save/7) is in file.inc so it's availability depends on a place you are using it. Sometimes it may not be loaded. Usually it should, but we can't tell without seeing what exactly you are doing.

Comment: I used this code in external php file (which is in root folder) I am using this for App. Drupal loading functions exists with this code.

Comment: i didn't understand.. what I have to do..?

Comment: You have to properly bootstrap Drupal at the beginning of your code? See the most upvoted answer in the question I linked - that's a sketch of what you need to put in your script to get access to Drupal functions.

Comment: I tried using bootstrap properly but I think it is not the problem..from the below lines of code, upto "step1 - exit" result array is displaying fine. If I remove exit; after step1 it is going to error page...
$account = user_load($uid);
print_r($account);
echo "step1";
exit;
$file = file_save($file);
echo"step2"; exit;

Comment: If you bootstrapped properly and have *another* problem, post your new code and [ask a new question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Closing as a duplicate is not a punishment, it's a way to promptly redirect you where answer for your problem as-is are posted, and to encourage you to post different question when you explore these answers. Just as the gray box below says, really.

Comment: You know, I sometimes vote **my own** questions as duplicates, too!